# What is causing System.AccessViolationException when I access an ADODB Field's Value?

Tags: .net, winforms, access-violation, adodb, npgsql

I am connecting to a PostgreSQL database from a .Net web service (both on a Windows XP machine).  On a few occasions recently, on a few different computers, we have received `System.AccessViolationException` errors.

One stack trace I was able to obtain showed that it was occuring when I took an ADODB.recordset and obtained the value of a field.
e.g.

```
Dim rs as ADODB.Recordset = 'initialize recordset via a query to database
MsgBox(rs("fieldName").Value)
```

This does not always fail; it rarely fails.  We ran memtest on one of the computers and found no problems.

What could the problem be?  If it's the driver, what are my options?

Comment: It's the provider.  Get a better one or ask help from the provider provider.  http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/

Comment: Hans-thank you.  Is a provider the same thing as a driver?  At some point we expected to begin using npgsql, but for now I would be interested in simply patching this bug.  Should I just be picking from one of these?  http://www.postgresql.org/download/products/2

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is try to upgrade the ADODB provider (sometimes called a driver).  This may represent a rare bug of some sort that may have been fixed.  However the fact that it rarely fails is a bit of a red flag to me and suggests some sort of concurrency problem somewhere.  Is this a multi-threaded application? What are other threads doing at the time?  Is it possible this is a race condition?

A second thing to check would be if some values can consistently crash the program.  Maybe there are embedded nulls in byteas or something?

Most likely however, this is an issue with the driver.  If you see any  issue that is similar, that's always the place to start.